# Can Rust macros be shared across editions?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros, rust-2018, rust-2021

Say a Rust 2018 macro defines an `async` function inside it. The syntax it would use would be incompatible with Rust 2015. So if you're compiling your crate with 2015 edition, wouldn't this expanded code from the macro conflict with that?

I'm not that familiar with inner workings of either procedural or declarative macros, but I imagine they need to produce edition-specific code, because their output is going to be treated the same as the rest of the code. If so, how can I share macro exports across edition boundaries. Do I need to re-write them on a per-edition basis? That doesn't seem scalable especially if editions are supposed to be released every 3 years or so.

Comment: Macros are "tagged" with their edition, so i think it should be fine to export a macros from a different edition.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I don't really have a codebase of Rust 2015 and Rust 2018. 2018-2021 is a very small gap that I don't think will be able to test in the macro. And though I can create a crate in Rust 2015 for testing, I'm not familiar with Rust 2015 at all and I've tried avoiding it (looks ugly). I asked this question out of curiosity, I don't have a need for it in production nor do I have an idea if this would occur in production (though I don't see a reason why it wouldn't).

Comment: @Jerboas86 so does that mean that the macros being hygenic and all can still be used across thread boundaries, or just that they wouldn't compile in a different edition so I can fearlessly export them?

Comment: A macro is part of your code. It has no reason to be handled differently. There's rarely something in your code which doesn't cross editions (up at least) and it's not more frequent in macros

Comment: @DenysSéguret The reason I say this, is say a Rust 2018 macro defines an async function inside it. The syntax it would use would be incompatible with Rust 2015. So if you're compiling your crate with 2015 edition, wouldn't this expanded code from the macro conflict with that?

Comment: The parsing of the macro is done in its own edition, and the lower level of representation are shared between editions, so it will compile and run.

Comment: Thanks @Jerboas86 for the clear and concise answer. If you want, you can publish it as a proper answer so I can accept it and close the question.

Comment: I will try but i never write a macro in my all life ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, macros developed under one edition can be used by code in other editions.

This was carefully planned as part of the Edition mechanism to prevent ecosystem stagnation. For macros in particular, the [Rust Edition Guide explains this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/editions/advanced-migrations.html#macro-hygiene) in more detail:

> Macros use a system called "edition hygiene" where the tokens within a macro are marked with which edition they come from. This allows external macros to be called from crates of varying editions without needing to worry about which edition it is called from.

An example is given for a macro which only works in Edition 2015:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! foo {
    () => {
        let dyn = 1;
        println!("it is {}", dyn);
    };
}
```

This uses `dyn` as an identifier, which is illegal in Rust 2018. However, since this macro was written in the 2015 Edition, any code written in this context is parsed and interpreted under the rules of that edition, in isolation from the caller's code. Thanks to this "hygiene" of macros, they can be seamlessly used in Rust 2018, 2021, or any other edition.

The same thing applies to *macros written in more recent editions*. Even if a procedural macro declares an `async` function, there is ultimately a common ground which does not depend on this syntax ([MIR](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/index.html)).

The only exception to this, of course, is when [migrating existing code between editions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/editions/advanced-migrations.html#migrating-macros).

Answer (score 3):

One of the rules of rust editions is that crates should be interoperable even if their are not from the same edition. [(source)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/editions/index.html)

This rule applies also to macros, thanks to edition hygiene property. Each macro spans are tagged with their edition [(source code)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e249ce6b2345587d6e11052779c86adbad626dff/compiler/rustc_span/src/hygiene.rs), and When a macro is expanded, the parsing step is made in its declaration edition, not in the edition call site.

In the lower level of representation difference between rust editions doesn't exist anymore, and so everything compiles and run [(source)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html)

Nevertheless, migration problem with macros can occur when the macro is defined and not used in a crate which migrates. In this case, `cargo fix --edition` will not work correctly.